# Adding spinner via java code rather than XML in Tabwidget

Tags: android, tabwidget

I'm new to android. Recently I learn how to create Tabwidget. This function is useful. But I find that I cannot add the widgets I want in R.layout.xxxx. So I try to do it by java code. But unfortunately it failed.

By using XML, I do the following. The program works without problem.

```
public class ShowBalanceActivity extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener
{
  private Spinner monthview;
  private ArrayAdapter monthadapter;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.balance);

        monthadapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                this, R.array.months, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        monthadapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
        monthview = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.monthlist);

 monthview.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
 monthview.setAdapter(monthadapter);

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) 
    {

    }

}
```

For the Java code part, I use the following,

```
public class BalanceLayout extends TabActivity implements TabHost.TabContentFactory
{

    private Activity activity;
    private LayoutInflater inflaterHelper = null;  
    private Spinner monthview = null;
    private LinearLayout layout;
    private static final String Tab1 = "By Date";
    private static final String Tab2 = "By Categories";
    private ArrayAdapter <String> monthadapter = null;

    public BalanceLayout (Activity a) 
    {  
           activity = a;  
           inflaterHelper = a.getLayoutInflater();  
    }

public View addCustomView(String id)
    {  

        layout = new LinearLayout(activity);  
        layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);  

        if(id.equals(Tab1))
        {  

            Spinner monthview = new Spinner(activity);
         ArrayAdapter <String> monthadapter = new ArrayAdapter <String> (this,
                   android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, MONTHS);
            monthadapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
            monthview.setAdapter(monthadapter);

            monthview.setOnItemSelectedListener(
                    new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() 
                    {
                        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) 
                        {

                        }

                        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) 
                     {

                     }


                    });
            layout.addView(monthview,  
                    new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));  

        }  

        else if(id.equals(Tab2))
        {  

        }  

        return layout;  
    } 

}
```

But it causes force close when I execute the program. It seems that I cannot use findViewById method to create the view like XML.

I read many documentations and search android docs and internet. I cannot find the solution. Hope that some of you know what happened to my code and solution to solve

Thanks !!

Tom

Answer (score 0):

After I checked my code and debug. Finally it is easy to solve. But originally I don't know why. Then I isolate the problem by only inserting textview.

TextView tv = new TextView(activity);
tv.setText("This is a text view");

layout.addView(tv, new 
LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

The problem for my code is using "this" not "activity". It is because I want to create layout dynamically not using content factory or intent method. So "this" was replaced by activity. Then the problem is solved. But I spent much time to troubleshoot. Android is amazing

monthadapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                    activity, R.array.months, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
            monthadapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);